# Selecting kotlin Int from Room database issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, annotation-processing

I have updated Room to latest version and moved to using ksp instead of kapt. After fixing migration issues I have found strange one. I have in my DAO following code:

```
@Query("SELECT ${ExpeditionEntity.ColumnId} FROM ${ExpeditionEntity.TableName} LIMIT 1")
fun getExpeditionId(): Single<Int>
```

However after generating Impl file with ksp I'm receiving following results:

```
 @Override
  public Single<Integer> getExpeditionId() {
    final String _sql = "SELECT id FROM expedition LIMIT 1";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
    return RxRoom.createSingle(new Callable<Integer>() {
      @Override
      public Integer call() throws Exception {
        final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, _statement, false, null);
        try {
          final int _result;
          if(_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            _result = _cursor.getInt(0);
          } else {
            _result = 0;
          }
          if(_result == null) {
            throw new EmptyResultSetException("Query returned empty result set: " + _statement.getSql());
          }
          return _result;
        } finally {
          _cursor.close();
        }
      }

      @Override
      protected void finalize() {
        _statement.release();
      }
    });
  }
```

which causes error on the compilation "bad operand types for binary operator '=='
first type:  int
second type: "

as _result variable is used as java regular integer (int) which have no nullability possible. Do you know maybe some workarounds or proper solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result to be nullable then use `Int?`

e.g. the generated java is then:-

```
try {
  final Integer _result;
  if(_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    if (_cursor.isNull(0)) {
      _result = null;
    } else {
      _result = _cursor.getInt(0);
    }
  } else {
    _result = null;
  }
  return _result;
} finally {
  _cursor.close();
  _statement.release();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I give it a try. I don't want to be nullable but if it helps java code, than what can I do :)

Comment: I cannot use it :( RxJava3 is not supporting nullability as type :) I can of course workaround with selecting full object and mapping to particular column.
Also I'm wondering if this is bug on code generator as this was working with previous versions